# Converting certain strings with a list into a nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like so:

```
['Man City', 'Chelsea', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Chelsea, Real Madrid, Sevilla', 'West Brom, Sunderland, PSG', 'Man City', 'Man City']
```

However, I want to change it so the strs with multiple teams become a list within the list

```
['Man City', 'Chelsea', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Man City', ['Chelsea', 'Real Madrid', 'Sevilla'], ['West Brom', 'Sunderland', 'PSG'], 'Man City', 'Man City']
```

Comment: There is no list in the list. It is still a string list.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What does "the strs with multiple teams" mean? Where the output says, for example, `'[Chelsea, Real Madrid, Sevilla]'`, did you mean `['Chelsea', 'Real Madrid', 'Sevilla']`? Please read [ask] and think about the logical steps needed to solve the problem. For example, can you write code that tells whether one of the original strings has multiple team names? Can you write code that creates the list for one of those strings? Can you write code that applies this process to each element of the list? If you put those things together, does it not solve the problem?

Comment: Check for comma and space `', '` in the string and if present - split at it

Comment: `[str([x]) if ',' in x else x for x in data]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
l = ['Man City', 'Chelsea', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Chelsea, Real Madrid, Sevilla', 'West Brom, Sunderland, PSG', 'Man City', 'Man City']
print([x.split(", ") if ',' in x else x for x in l])
```

Result:

```
['Man City', 'Chelsea', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Man City', 'Man City', ['Chelsea', 'Real Madrid', 'Sevilla'], ['West Brom', 'Sunderland', 'PSG'], 'Man City', 'Man City']
```

Edit to reflect comment. New output and edited code.

Comment: Really appreciate that, I realised I made a mistake in the question and would ideally want to separate the teams within the nested lists

Comment: @order66 See edit. :)